# sqlbulkcopy batch sizing in relation to number of rows in datatable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sqlbulkcopy

Do i need to ensure that each batch is completely full? ie if i had a datatable with 12028 rows, could i just use a batch size of 10k and it would automatically create 2 batches, 1 with 10k in and 1 with 2028 in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN: SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize.aspx) --

> If the SqlBulkCopy instance has been declared without the
>   UseInternalTransaction option in effect, rows are sent to the server
>   BatchSize rows at a time, but no transaction-related action is taken.
>   If UseInternalTransaction is in effect, each batch of rows is inserted
>   as a separate transaction.
>
> The BatchSize property can be set at any time. If a bulk copy is
>   already in progress, the current batch is sized according to the
>   previous batch size. Subsequent batches use the new size. If the
>   BatchSize is initially zero and changed while a WriteToServer
>   operation is already in progress, that operation loads the data as a
>   single batch. Any subsequent WriteToServer operations on the same
>   SqlBulkCopy instance use the new BatchSize.

Based on this information, I am inclined to believe that setting batch size to 10k rows and you provide 12k+, multiple batches will be created.

Comment: Aye its not particularly clear. I think i will just assume it will for the moment unless anyone else chips in. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You were right i finally got my program working and tested what the above, ie uploading 15 rows with a batch size of 10. All rows were added. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!!